# Canonical form of a 4x4 matrix with 1 real eigenvalue and 2 linearly independent eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

> Suppose A is a $4 \times4$ matrix with a single real eigenvalue and two linearly independent eigenvectors. Describe the possible canonical forms for $A$ and show that $A$ may indeed be transformed into one of these canonical forms. Describe explicitly the conditions under which A is transformed into a particular form.

Attempt：Jordan blocks are either of the form $\lambda I$ or $\lambda I$ with 1's on the superdiagonal (above the middle one). Since $A$ is 4x4, we can expect its Jordan form $J$ to be either two $2 \times 2$ blocks or a $3\times 3$ block and a $1$ block....

And then I am kind of lost... I am not sure how having 2 L.I eigenvectors would help/change the situation, and I don't know how to answer the subsequent questions regarding conditions of $A$.

Comment: Why couldn't a $4\times4$ matrix have a JNF with only one block? How might you eliminate that possibility?

Answer (score 1):

Let $ A $ a matrix with  a single real eigenvalue $ \lambda $ and two linearly
independent eigenvectors .

so $ dim Ker(A-\lambda I )=2 $ and $ dim R(A-\lambda I) =2 $.

Let $ V_{1} $ an eigenvector, choose $ V_{2}\in R(A-\lambda I ) $ such that $(A-\lambda I)V_{2}=V_{1}  $

i.e $ AV_{2}=\lambda V_{2}+V_{1} $

Let $ V_{3} $ the second eigenvector, choose $ V_{4}\in R(A-\lambda I ) $ such that $(A-\lambda I)V_{4}=V_{3}  $

i.e $ AV_{4}=\lambda V_{4}+V_{3} $

Now we get $ A\begin{pmatrix}
 &  &  &  \\ 
V_{1} ; & V_{2} ;& V_{3} ;& V_{4} \\ 
 &  &  & 
\end{pmatrix}  $ $  =$ $ \begin{pmatrix}
 &  &  &  \\ 
\lambda V_{1} ;& \lambda V_{2}+V_{1} ;& \lambda V_{3} ;& \lambda V_{4}+V_{3} \\ 
 &  &  & 
\end{pmatrix}  $

$  =$ $ \begin{pmatrix}
 &  &  &  \\ 
V_{1} ;& V_{2} ;& V_{3} ;& V_{4} \\ 
 &  &  & 
\end{pmatrix}  $  $ \begin{pmatrix}
\lambda & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & \lambda & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & \lambda & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & \lambda
\end{pmatrix}  $

so $ T^{-1}AT=  \begin{pmatrix}
\lambda & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & \lambda & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & \lambda & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & \lambda
\end{pmatrix}  $  whehre $ T=  \begin{pmatrix}
 &  &  &  \\ 
V_{1} ;& V_{2} ;& V_{3} ;& V_{4} \\ 
 &  &  & 
\end{pmatrix}   $ invertible because the vectors $ V_{i} $ are linearly independent.

now assume that $ V_{1} $ and $ V_{2} $ are the eigenvectors

choose $ V_{3}\in R(A-\lambda I ) $ such that $(A-\lambda I)V_{3}=V_{2}  $

choose $ V_{4}\in R(A-\lambda I ) $ such that $(A-\lambda I)V_{4}=V_{3}  $
we get as previously that $ T^{-1}AT=  \begin{pmatrix}
\lambda & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & \lambda & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & \lambda & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & \lambda
\end{pmatrix}  $